# Print each value of list element using xsl

Tags: xslt

I wonder if there is a way to loop on each Info element and take each value of Value element and Set it in temp variable using xsl

```
<list>
        <Info>
            <Child>John</Child>
            <Value>5</Value>
        </Info>

        <Info>
            <Child>Jo</Child>
            <Value>6</Value>
        </Info>

        <Info>
            <Child>Amanda</Child>
            <Value>7</Value>
        </Info>

</list>
```

Comment: XPath is the expression language in XSLT and using `/list/Info/Value` is a simple XPath expression selecting all those `Value` elements. If you want a variable bound to the elements use e.g. `<xsl:variable name="values" select="/list/Info/Value"/>`. No need for "loops", whatever you that believe to be in the context of XSLT.

Comment: if I want to print the second info that has jo as child and 6 as value. how that can be done ?

Comment: The second `Info` element is selected with `/list/Info[2]`.Try an XPath and XSLT tutorial.